# Spring Security @PreAuthorize based on custom boolean property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, user-roles

I have an application where the user enters custom roles name and privileges.
Example, the user can create a role named "`Human Resources`" that has the following properties :

```
showDashboard = true;
showSuppliers = false;
showEmployees = true;
```

I want to restrict `getSuppliers` service based on the `showSuppliers` property.

```
@PreAuthorize("WHEN showSuppliers IS TRUE")
public Page<Supplier> getSuppliers();
```

Role entity :

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private boolean showDashboard;
    private boolean showSuppliers;
    private boolean showEmployees;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference a bean in the `PreAuthorize` expression. First this bean/component:

```java
@Component("authorityChecker")
public class AuthorityChecker {

    public boolean canShowSuppliers(Authentication authentication) {
        for (Authority authority : authentication.getAuthorites()) {
            Role role = (Role)authority; // may want to check type before to avoid ClassCastException
            if (role.isShowSuppliers()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the annotation to this will be:

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authorityChecker.canShowSuppliers(authentication)")
public Page<Supplier> getSuppliers();
```

It will pass the current user's Authentication object to the bean/component above.

Comment: I've based on your answer to create a component that returns the whole role object from the authenticated user, and then I check every property on the @PreAuthorize.